# Google App Engine deploy react app version size significantly different

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

[image]

I refactored an entire web app that was ejected in a new react app created with create-react-app.

The code is almost the same.

The problem is the huge different in the size of the two version deployed in Google App Engine and I can't manage to understand why.

Any clue?

Comment: Others are seeing the same thing.  It doesn't matter unless you are close to limits and you are not.

Comment: Hello, I created a [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/180717730) to redirect this concern to the engineering team, this should give us more information on why is this happening